# EXCEL: chart numerosity of items along time based on start-end date

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts

I don't know how to explain better my case so I will go strait to the practical example:
I have this excel table:

| Computer | Date Start | Date End |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Server1 | 2022-01-01 00 | 2022-02-10 00 |
| Server2 | 2022-01-02 00 | 2022-02-15 00 |
| Server3 | 2022-01-03 00 | 2022-02-20 00 |

So three servers, started in different days and destroyed after a while.
How can I chart the whole month of January 2022 in order to show me how many servers were active at certain day?
Based on the table:

- first of january only 1 server was active
- second of january the chart will peak at 2 since there are two servers running
- third of january the chart will peak at 3 since there are three servers running
- from 4th jan till 10th of feb a constant line at 3
- then the 11th of feb back to two
- and so on

Is it possible to such chart with Excel?

Thanks,
Evan

Answer (score 0):

(Not sure if this is what you are look)

1. Setup a column listing each day of the month.
2. Next to it, insert the following formula:

   ```
   =SUMPRODUCT(--(B$2:B$4<=G2),--(C$2:C$4>=G2))
   ```
3. Insert a chart with those two columns

[image]

Comment: Thanks @cybernetic.nomad this is exactly what I was looking for.
Need to study better the SUMPRODUCT function to match my case.
In the meanwhile I found also another method, I will post in another answer.
Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Found this alternative method using the COUNTIFS function:

=COUNTIFS(B:B,"<="&G2,C:C,">="&G2)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D2zWy.png)